# How to use Test-Path including a regex

Tags: powershell

I would like to check if the file Test.txt exists in a specific directory (folder name with 16-digits).

I tried for example following command:

```
Test-Path "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\Test\([0-9]{16})\Test.txt"
```

Following command cannot be used in my situation.

```
 Test-Path "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\Test\*\Test.txt"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the wildcards `?*` you may use ranges `[0-9]` in folder/file names but that doesn't mean you can use full fledged RegEx here. Theoretically you could use `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]...` but IIRC there is a limit on the number of ranges usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test-Path` will return $True/$False, to achieve something similar you can do:

```
((Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\Test\*\Test.txt" | 
    where FullName -match "\\Test\\\d{16}\\Test.txt$").Count -gt 0)
```

But that will not reveal which folders matched.

Answer (score 3):

This would be one way of doing that:

```
# This is for PowerShell version 3.0 and up. If you are using an older version, use
# Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\Test" | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '\d{16}' }

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\Test" -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d{16}' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $fileName = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'Test.txt'
        if (Test-Path -Path $fileName -PathType Leaf) {
            Write-Host "$fileName exists"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "$fileName does not exist"
        }
    }
```