# Windows - Command To Find Out If A Registry Path Exists Or Not

Tags: windows, command-line, command, key, registry

I need help with a Windows command that output's if a registry path exists, or not. For example, if the registry path I have specified below exists on my Windows Machine, it should output something like, "registry path exists": `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\NTLMMinClientSec`

I have not been successful in trying to create such a code, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from Powershell using the Test-Path cmdlet

```
Test-Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\NTLMMinClientSec"
```

You'll get "True" if it exists "False" if not.

Comment: Thank you very much that is perfect. I had another question if it is possible to implement in the code? I would like to check if a registry key exists within a users HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2990211406-3548698811-2423315665-500 path and the numbering/naming of that path always changes. Would regex work for powershell?

Comment: I've got this regex to match: ^S-1-5-21-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]{3,}

Comment: @Hasan you can't use [fully fledged regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778870/how-to-use-test-path-including-a-regex) there but you can do a limited amount with ranges so you might be able to do  "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]" but I've never tried it personally

Comment: ok thank you for the info, I have tested this but it did not work.